# Universal Links : Code Signing problems - cannot Build

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, ios-universal-links

I followed all the instructions regarding Universal Links implementation:

> i. Add callback in appDelegate
>
> ii. Enable ‘Associated Domains’ on your app ID
>
> iii. Enable ‘Associated Domain’ on in your Xcode project
>
> iv. Add the proper domain url link
>
> v. Re-generate all provisioning profiles
>
> vi. Add the ‘apple-app-site-association’ file to my website ---> (NOT YET)

But I keep getting this code signing problem:

[image]

And after `Fix Issue` :

[image]

All this happens only when I build into a Device, not in the Simulator.
Any clues?

Comment: Are you certain you're signed into the correct Apple ID in Xcode Preferences? You could also double check [Provisioning Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/) and [Certificates](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/)

Comment: Cross check all steps with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609667/how-to-support-universal-links-in-ios-app-and-setup-server-for-it