# Universal Link opens my app but doesn't call application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-universal-links

I'm trying to implement Universal Links in my app. I read a lot of tutorials and followed this one to the letter:
[How to support Universal Links in iOS App and setup server for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609667/how-to-support-universal-links-in-ios-app-and-setup-server-for-it/35609668#35609668)

When I click a universal link my app successfully opens but `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler` in my AppDelegate.m file isn't called so I can't direct to a specific page in the app.

My `apple-app-site-association` file is on https and for paths I put `[ "*", "/" ]`. I triple-checked app prefix and ID, confirmed AssociatedDomains is enabled both on the developer website and in my target. In the Associated Domains section I put my root domain as well as a second entry prepended with *. to handle all possible subdomains. I am testing on a real device, not on the simulator.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler {
    ALog(@"Did I get here?");
}
```

Can anyone provide advice as to what I should be looking at to figure out why `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler` isn't being called?

**Update:**

I used Apple's validation tool https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool and it gave this result:

> Link to Application
>
> Action required
>
> Could not extract required information for Universal Links. Learn how to implement the recommended Universal Links.
>
> Error no apps with domain entitlements
>   The entitlement data used to verify deep link dual authentication is from the current released version of your app. This data may take 48 hours to update.

I don't know if that has anything to do with my problem. I wouldn't think so, because I need to test my app to make sure I have Universal Links implemented properly before actually releasing the update.

Comment: Since your app is opening, you've already passed 99% of the usual problems with Universal Links. You don't need to worry about the message from Apple's validation tool — I've almost never seen that not present, and it is there on many implementations that work perfectly. What method are you using to be certain that the `continueUserActivity` handler isn't called?

Comment: I put an ALog statement on the first line which never gets printed. I did find that `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation` gets called, but again have no idea why. According to the documentation `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler` should be called.

Comment: Hmm. You are testing this on a physical device and not the simulator, correct? We might need to see an actual link example

Comment: The links are in the form of `mydomain://phase1/phase2?key1=var1&key2=var2#hash`. My current workaround is to just use `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation` but I'd still like to know why that is triggering and `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler` is not.

Comment: Hard to tell from that example — looks almost like a uri scheme, in which case openURL would be correct. Could we get a full example of an actual link?

Comment: I think I may be misunderstanding universal links. I was using `MyCustomSceme://phase1/` which I guess is only for deep linking... so universal links are supposed to look like web links, e.g. `http://example.com/phase1/`? If that's the case then I'm not as close to figuring it out as I thought, because those links do not open my app.

Comment: Ahh, yes. Those are URI scheme links. Universal Links are normal http links. Here is a good overview: https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9

Comment: @primehalo if you have Google Analytics and Localytics implemented in your app, you might want to take a look this git issue: https://github.com/BranchMetrics/ios-branch-deep-linking/issues/485

Comment: I know it's an old question but did you fix the issue at the end? I have exactly the same problem :(

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1):

If Google Analytics or some Firebase features is used in the app, it may be caused by method swizzling. Adding the following method in `application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)` solves the issue for me. I think disabling method swizzling will work too.

```
private func swizzleSelectors() {
    
    let aClass: AnyClass! = object_getClass(UIApplication.shared.delegate)
    let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(aClass, #selector(self.application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)))
    let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(aClass, #selector(UIApplication.shared.delegate!.application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)))
    if let originalMethod = originalMethod, let swizzledMethod = swizzledMethod {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays the problem could be that the message is not sent to AppDelegate, but to its successor: scene delegate. So use then this method instead:

```
UIWindowSceneDelegate::scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity)
```