# Error with Universal Links on phone w/ iOS 13

Tags: ios, ios13, ios-universal-links

I am seeing the below error in iOS 13 when trying to setup an app with universal links.  Has anyone seen this or know what it means?

I am seeing this error in the device console for the swcd process.

> `Error getting enterprise-managed associated domains data. If this device is not enterprise-managed, this is normal:`
>
> `Error Domain=SWCErrorDomain Code=1701 "Failed to get associated domain data from ManagedConfiguration framework." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Failed to get associated domain data from ManagedConfiguration framework., Line=250, Function=<private>}`

When I install the same app on an iOS 12 device it works perfectly fine.  Any thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: I hadn't found this in my searches earlier, but it appears I am not the only one https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123554

Comment: Is your device managed by an MDM? It looks like it is trying to look up the associated domain from some kind of enterprise MDM service.

Comment: I got same error when install the application (iPhone 7 plus, iOS 13.3.1). Do you have any idea to resolve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that upgrading to iOS 13.2.2 solves the issue.
There is no official confirmation about this, but is seems resolved on iOS 13.2.2.

Comment: iOS 13.1.3 upgrade to 13.2.3, still have the problem.

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: iOS 13.5, still the same

Answer (score 0):

There may be some different places that cause this problem. Note that the format of AASA file seems to be changed recently. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63894613/4963585).

If the delegate isn't called, and there are some Google Analysis or Firebase features in the app, then it may be caused by method swizzling. If that's the case, please refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63895002/4963585).