# How to implement DeepLinking If user don't have app then?

Tags: ios, swift, laravel-5, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I have 3 requirement for DeepLinking or Universal Links to my project.

1. If user is having the application then URL should redirect to application with content.
2. If user don't have the application then it should redirect to Appstore.
3. If user don't have the application then it should redirect to Appstore and after download the app it should go to that page with data which I am sending with URL.

Links which I followed:

1. https://www.raywenderlich.com/128948/universal-links-make-connection
2. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html.
3. http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/deep-linking-using-custom-url-scheme/.
4. http://blogs.innovationm.com/deferred-deep-linking-in-ios-with-universal-link/
5. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/shared_web_credentials/preparing_your_app_and_website_to_share
6. http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-deep-linking-in-swift/.

What I understood is:

> Creating and Uploading the Association File and for this I have to follow some steps:
>
> Adding support for universal links is easy. There are three steps you need to take:
>
> Create an apple-app-site-association file that contains JSON data about the URLs that your app can handle. Upload the apple-app-site-association file to your HTTPS web server. You can place the file at the root of your server or in the .well-known subdirectory. Prepare your app to handle universal links.
>
> Creating and Uploading the Association File
>
> To create a secure connection between your website and your app, you establish a trust relationship between them. You establish this relationship in two parts:
>
> An apple-app-site-association file that you add to your website
>   A com.apple.developer.associated-domains entitlement that you add to your app
>
> Preparing Your App to Handle Universal Links.
>   In your com.apple.developer.associated-domains entitlement, include a list of the domains that your app wants to handle as universal links. To do this in Xcode, open the Associated Domains section in the Capabilities tab and add an entry for each domain that your app supports, prefixed with applinks:, such as applinks:www.mywebsite.com.

Problem is: I followed all steps and I have a url I added it in the domain in my Associated Domain.

Example: `https://<My_Domain>/anything`. 
Now Backend is generating URL and sending.

We are using `Http` server.

Example:

```
Route::get('appstore',function(){ return redirect()->away('https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/whatsapp-messenger/id310633997?mt=8');});
```

Problem is when I am clicking on that URL I am not getting any popup for already app and also After download how data I will get ?

Am  missing something or backend is missing something?

Comment: Please note this question needed a lot of editing to make it readable. In particular, if you wish to copy+paste material from elsewhere (such as a manual or tutorial) to illustrate what steps you took, you **must use a quote block** to show that it is not your speech.

Comment: Also, if you use `<angle brackets>` then any material will disappear within them unless you use backticks. Please always use the preview window and proof-read your question before publishing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to support Universal Links in iOS App and setup server for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609667/how-to-support-universal-links-in-ios-app-and-setup-server-for-it)

Comment: I have written a detailed solution document under this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266797/deeplink-solution-for-ios-and-android-apps-works-in-facebook

Comment: @kishor0011 Let me know if you find the solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like you are trying to accomplish **deferred deep linking**, which means you route the user to the content if the app is installed or you route the user to the app store to download the app and present them the content once the app is opened. This is very difficult to do by yourself and I'll explain more in a bit.

It looks like you are setting up your universal links correctly but the redirect to the app store is fairly hacky. Universal Links are meant to be used to redirect users to the web version, which means bringing them to the app store instead is no easy task.

If you do get the user to the app store, deferred deep linking which is just directing them to the content after they install the app is [nearly impossible](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-build-a-linking-solution-for-every-device/) to do yourself without using a third-party service like [Branch](http://branch.io). Branch also will allow you to push users back to the app store to download the app, if that's the user experience your looking for.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Webserver can user to App Store if app is not installed but in this case I want to get content also.

Comment: That is where deferred deep linking comes in. It is how you can route information around the app store. You could try and [build it yourself](https://blog.branch.io/deferred-deep-linking-with-device-snapshotting/), but it's nearly impossible.

Comment: OK I will try it. Thanks