# Can I add a deep link in a laravel web view phone application?

Tags: laravel, webview, deep-linking

I tried a lot to add a deep link in '< a >' tag to open up a page in another app but it didn't seem to work from the web view application. Worked from the phone browser though, but only for few IOS phones.

Any ideas if this is gonna work on a webview? or any work around to make it work?

Thanks !

Comment: are you looking for info on how to deep-link? see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609667/how-to-support-universal-links-in-ios-app-and-setup-server-for-it

Comment: @YehudaSchwartz Nope. For example: I want to link a facebook deep link page to my web-view phone application. But the problem is, its not working. My phone application is just a web-view of my website.