# iOS - Link from web browser opens an app in iOS app although it should be redirected to web browser

Tags: ios, web, safari, apple-app-site-association

There is an iOS app.

There is a link on a web:
<a href="https://somedomain.com/forgotPassword?key=<some_hash>"

In iOS app, there is an `apple-app-site-association` file with config

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
         "appID": "....",
         "paths": ["NOT /forgotPassword", "*"]
      },
      {
         "appID": "....",
         "paths": ["NOT /forgotPassword", "*"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

but the redirection happens from that link on a web to the iOS app, although this is in configuration: `"NOT /forgotPassword"` and redirection to iOS app should be intercepted and blocked.

( I followed instructions from: [How to support Universal Links in iOS App and setup server for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609667/how-to-support-universal-links-in-ios-app-and-setup-server-for-it/35609668#35609668) )

I tried `"paths": ["NOT /forgotPassword", "*"]` as well as `"paths": ["*", "NOT /forgotPassword"]`

**How do I configure it so opening links in browser would be redirected to iOS app (this part is working), EXCEPT when client calls https://somedomain.com/forgotPassword...**

Sidenote:
This part: opening links in browser would be redirected to IOS app - was working fine and still works fine when I had `"paths": ["*"]`
but when I introduced NOT clause, as is suggested in the stack overflow link above that I provided, this doesn't work.
Should I format it in some other way?

P.S. I'm a web developer, so if there are steps to be taken on iOS part, please be as concise and detailed as possible so I can forward it to iOS team.

EDIT:
In the meantime, I also tried these combinations:

```
"paths": ["*", "NOT /forgotPassword?key=?"]
"paths": ["NOT /forgotPassword?key=?", "*"]
```

Comment: In my case Not working when i hit url from the browser and it work when i click url from messenger or whatsapp. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved when mobile team built a new app. All the time they were just retrying while I was reconfiguring apple-app-site-association file and recycling pool in IIS.

However, they needed to rebuild their app in order for this to work.